# Determine bluetooth state for beacon ranging in iOS 11

Tags: ios, bluetooth, beacon

In iOS 11, a user can disable bluetooth from both control centre and settings. If bluetooth is disabled in control centre, the beacon ranging could still work. I tried to use `didUpdateState` in central manager. It only gives me `CBManagerStatePoweredOff` when Bluetooth is disable in either way.
Is there a way to find out whether Bluetooth is capable of ranging? I also tried `isRangingAvailable`. It always returns true on my device.

Comment: Do you get a callback to rangingBeaconsDidFailForRegion

Comment: Yes thanks, I did, It reported kCLErrorDomain error 16.

Comment: So that is your answer, yes?  If you get the error code, you know Bluetooth is not capable of ranging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CoreLocation delegate, implement the following method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
 rangingBeaconsDidFailFor region: CLBeaconRegion, 
                withError error: Error) {
   // Ranging is not available.  Do something here.
}
```